# Why do I see tweets of people I don't follow?

Tags: twitter

These *are not* retweets. What I'm seeing is tweets of people who follow people I follow. For example if I follow John Doe I'll see a tweet from someone who follows John Doe too. At the top of the tweet it tells me "John Doe follows". How can I get rid if this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not seeing favourite tweets? This behaviour was implemented in 2014:

[Anger on Twitter as new feature posts favourites to followers' timelines](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/aug/18/twitter-posts-favourites-followers-timelines)

You can verify this by checking to see if there is a gold star visible on the tweet itself.
As far as I am aware, there is not currently a way to disable this globally. You should be able to do it on an individual basis, similarly to disabling retweets from a specific person.